# how to git push with maven

Tags: git, maven

As part of my build I am creating some files. I would like maven to commit and push these files.

I have looked at the maven-scm plugin and I can't see how to do a push. I can see commit but not push.

Is there any way to do a git push with maven?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html#pushChanges

> **pushChanges**
>
> Should distributed changes be pushed to the central repository? For
> many distributed SCMs like Git, a change like a commit is only stored
> in your local copy of the repository. Pushing the change allows your
> to more easily share it with other users.
>
> Type: boolean
>
> Since: 1.4
>
> Required: No
>
> Expression: ${pushChanges}
>
> Default: true

(Without more context, it is hard to tell if this is really a good idea or not. That depends.)

Comment: totally agree with your comment on whether or not this is a good idea. Time will tell I guess. But thanks, did not see that parameter!

Comment: @MichaelWiles no prob. Please accept the answer also if this was the information needed :)

Comment: but that <pushChanges>true</pushChanges> doesn't actually cause a push. Maybe there is something else that I need to do to enable it...

Comment: interesting version 1.8 of maven-scm-plugin pushChanges does not work. 1.5 it does

Comment: it should default to true anyway, so might be something you'd like to report a bug on.

Comment: this is not an answer, this question remains without an answer

Comment: @Shaybc can you clarify why you think this is not the answer? OP confirmed this did the push as requested in the question