# Using Maven plugins (except exec) to do a git push

Tags: git, maven

I want to use maven which already has the SCM configured via the `pom.xml`/`settings.xml` file to perform

```
git push origin release:master
```

I know I can do it via the `exec` plugin, but that would mean I would have to configure `git` with the credentials which uses a different set than that of what Maven is already using.  I am thinking there should be something in the [maven-scm-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/checkin-mojo.html) that would do the work but I can't find it there at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to git push with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122471/how-to-git-push-with-maven)

Comment: [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/) does a lot of SCM actions, maybe looking at how it does that would help you?

Comment: it did those actions but only on the current branch, I want to push those changes into another branch.  I almost got it but it still had a few issues like having it trigger more than once.

Comment: Note that mvn scm: just execs git... but it does take care of authentication still

Answer (score 2):

`mvn scm:checkin -Dmessage='my message'`

That will do git add/commit/push

Note that it requires commandline git to be installed